# Custom image upload

Tags: php, html, uploads

I'm trying to setup upload for for attachments for my custom post form.

At first I add to my `form` tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

For testing purposes I have two upload forms, but in future I'm gonna implement only one form and use jQuery to append as many forms as I want.

```
    <fieldset class="images">
        <label for="images">Front of the Bottle</label>
        <input type="file" name="image1" id="bottle_front" size="50">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="images">
        <label for="images">Back of the Bottle</label>
        <input type="file" name="image2" id="bottle_rear" size="50">
    </fieldset>
```

in *PHP* I use:

```
    if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id);
            // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
            // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
        }
    }
```

and in *functions.php* I have functions which should handle this form.

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
 // check to make sure its a successful upload
 if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

 $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

 if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
 return $attach_id;
 }
```

everything works pefect if I just upload two images, but If I want to upload only one OR none, I get error my post_meta db:

```
O:8:"WP_Error":2:{s:6:"errors";a:1:{s:12:"upload_error";a:1:{i:0;s:21:"No file was uploaded.";}}s:10:"error_data";a:0:{}}
```

I tried inserting:
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] === 4) __return_false();
in functions.php but it does not work, how to tell my script that my form is empty?

Credits: [took this form from here](http://voodoopress.com/including-images-as-attachments-or-featured-image-in-post-from-front-end-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you are not returning correctly from function, Try this,

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler, $post_id, $setthumb=false) {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    // changes start
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        return __return_false();
    }
    // changes end

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb)
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

Comment: hello Vyas )
What are those asterisks used for?
My code does not execute at all

Comment: @Mpa4Hu remove asterisks, i have them to show you which line i have changed.

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, it's better to simply re-use the existing native function of Wordpress **featured images** 
that let's you upload images in your custom post type.

You can enable while registering your custom post adding the option

```
'supports' => array('thumbnail')
```

such as many other usefulle native functions